# how to call value that called from DB by array in form1 and used it to make condition in form2 by C#

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

i make class for table in my DB

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1.Database {
class Ques
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
    public Illnesses(int id,string title)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
    public static Ques[] getAll()
    {
        Ques[] arr = new Ques[100];
        connection con1 = new connection();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM ques;", con1.mycon());
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int counter = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Ques= new Ques(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1));
            arr[counter++] = temp;
        }
        con1.con.Close();
        return arr;
    } 
} }
```

and in  **form1** i called my **Table Rows** in database by **Array** to show in **button name like text** when i run the program and this **work perfectly** then transfer me to form2

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ques[] ques= Ques.getAll();
        button1.Text = ques[0].title;
        button2.Text = ques[1].title;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
} }
```

[And This is The Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opfoc.jpg),
**The Problem is** i need to make **if condition** in **form2** depend on (button 1, 2 OR rows i called from DB in buttons) That in **from1**

**To** output **different result** in **my Form2**

**my Form2**

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Ques[] ques= Ques.getAll();

        if (???????????)
        {
            button1.Text = ques[2].title;
            label1.Text = "this is ans Q1";
        }
        else if (????????????)
        {
            button1.Text = ques[3].title;
            label1.Text = "this is ans Q2";
        }

    }
```

[shape of form 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGfH6.jpg)

So what i should write in condition of form2 (place of question marks  ??????????)

**Thank everyone who can help :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can determine which button is clicked and button text is equal to the question text to write the condition.

You could define some property or fields in the form1. Then you could use `Application.OpenForms` method to access the property.

Key code:

```
form1.btn1text== "This is my q1" && form1.bt1clicked==true
form1.btn2text == "This is my q2" && form1.bt2clicked == true
```

Here is a code example you could refer to.

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string btn1text { get; set; }
        public string btn2text { get; set; }
        public  bool bt1clicked = false;
        public  bool bt2clicked = false;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bt1clicked = true;
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bt2clicked = true;
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Show();
            this.Hide();
      
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ques[] ques = Ques.getAll();
            button1.Text = ques[0].title;
            button2.Text = ques[1].title;
            btn1text = button1.Text;
            btn2text = button2.Text;
        }
```

Form2:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            
            Ques[] ques = Ques.getAll();

            if (form1.btn1text== "This is my q1" && form1.bt1clicked==true)
            {
                button1.Text = ques[2].title;
                label1.Text = "this is ans Q1";
            }
            else if (form1.btn2text == "This is my q2" && form1.bt2clicked == true)
            {
                button1.Text = ques[3].title;
                label1.Text = "this is ans Q2";
            }
        }
```

Tested result:

[image]